# How to make a gulp stream synchronous

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, gulp

plugin.js

```
module.exports = function(holder) {
  return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
    console.log('2')
    return callback(null, file);
  }
}
```

task

```
gulp.task('t', function() {
  console.log('1');
  var tmp = gulp.src(...).pipe(require('plugin')())
  console.log('3');
  return tmp;
});
```

The console result is:

> 1
>       3
>       2

But what I want is:

> 1
>       2
>       3

How could I do that?

Comment: I sense an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here. Why do you want this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make the stream synchronous. Instead you listen for the [`end` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) :

```
gulp.task('t', function() {
  console.log('1');
  return gulp.src(...)
   .pipe(require('plugin')())
   .on('end', function() {
      console.log('3');
   });
});
```